In order theory, is there a term for a set that upper bounds everything strictly lower than an element?
Suppose we have a partial order $(X, \leq)$, and for some element $x\in X$ we find a set $S\subseteq X$ where

No two elements of $S$ are comparable, so for any $s,t\in S$ we have $s\leq t$ if and only if $s=t$
All elements of $S$ are strictly less than $x$, so for any $s\in S$ we have $s\leq x$ and $x\nleq s$
All elements of $X$ which are less than $x$ are less than something in $S$, so for any $y \in X$ where $y\leq x$, either there is some $s\in S$ where $y\leq s$, or $y=x$

Note that for an element $x$, a set $S$ satisfying this need not exist. As a simple example, in the real numbers with the usual ordering, this set does not exist for any element. There is something to be said about infinite ascending chains here. Also, I'm pretty sure that if such a set $S$ exists, it would be unique.
I've asked this before on other platforms and been sent some interesting but ultimately unsatisfactory concepts. One was the idea of the covering relation, $x \lessdot y$ meaning $x<y$ and there is no $z$ where $x<z<y$. And yes, it is true that if for some $x$ this $S$ existed, then all the elements $s\in S$ would have $s\lessdot x$, but if the set $S$ doesn't exist, the set $\{s\in X\mid s\lessdot x\}$ would not satisfy the requirements. Another idea was finding sets whose meet was $x$, but that is also not sufficient, for example we could have two elements whose meet is $x$ and some infinite ascending chain whose elements are all less than $x$ and unrelated to the other two elements.
I'm tempted to just give this idea a name of my own choosing, maybe saying $x$ is depicted from below by $S$, but I'd rather use an existing term if it existed.

I don't believe this has a special name, but you describe the set of atoms of the partial order $(\{ y\in X: y\leq x \}, \geq)$. Note that the minimal element of this order is $x$. You also add the axiom that this partial order is atomic (which depends on the structure of $X$ as you correctly noted).
An atom $a$ is an element that is not $0$ (here not $x$) that is such that there is no $y$ with $0\lneq y\lneq a$ (here $a\lneq y\lneq x$). This covers your first two axioms, and assuming that the partial order is atomic is equivalent to the third.

Thankyou, though I think I will use the terms coatomic and coatoms.

Right, of course, there is a dual concept. So I guess you are looking at the coatoms of the coatomic partial order ${y: y\leq x}$.
